# Random Excel crashes xlsm

Tags: excel, vba

In my company I'm using Excel 2013 64bit and many xlsm files with some macros that use basic build in libraries. Occasionally I encounter a random "microsoft excel has stopped working" (- mostly on opening a file but last week it happened while I was just staring at the screen). 95% of the times making a copy of the file, so that excel would not see it as trusted, going to vba editor and compiling vba project manually and saving it would fix the problem, however it recently got simply annoing as frequency of those crashes went from 1/week to several per day. I think I waste like 30 minutes daily just on fixing  crashed files. So generally I know what to do when excel crash happens but I would like to know if there's something that can be done to prevent them from happening in the first place.

Also the crashed files work flawlessly on a machine with excel 2010 on it. Saving the file with E2010 also fixes the problem for E2013

Comment: The crashes I've had with Excel Macros in the past appear to be connected with running out of memory. The only (not ideal) work around I have for this (when crunching a lot of data) is to make sure that you only have the one workbook open!

Comment: I don't think it's the same case here, most of the time I don't exceed even a half of my RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64 bit Office has a lot of problems with VB code. These seem to be related to the pcode that get's generated when the code is compiled and so recompiling seems to fix them. There's a registry fix to force recompile, you need to set these two values:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.0\Common
Type:  DWORD

Name:  CompileOnDemand
Value:  0
```

and:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\
Type:  DWORD

Name:  ForceVBALoadFromSource
Value:  1
```

These two fixed it for me.

Comment: Is that Compile on Demand key the same as going in VBA Editor Tools>Options>General>Compile>"Compile on demand"?

Comment: Probably - I took those two from a posting on a website somewhere

Comment: sooo it took a while to check everything via our IT section, mainly bc this ForceVBA fix seemed to be related to an old MS Office patch (KB4011597), but just adding this value to registry fixes the problem